# PayPal Pro Hosted Solution and 3D Secure Cards

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-sandbox, website-payment-pro

I'm currently integrating the PayPal Pro hosted solution, the iFrame version, into an eCommerce solution.

Using the PayPal sandbox, I can process test Visa and MasterCard transactions fine, but my UK Maestro transactions are always denied, with the error message: 'This transaction can't be processed. Please pay with another card.'

Here is my form, that calls the iframe:

```
<form target="hss_iframe" name="form_iframe" method="post" action="https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/acquiringweb">    

<!-- paypal details -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXXXXXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
<input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EN">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/paypal_pro_return.php">
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="7783">

<!-- customer details -->
<input type="hidden" name="buyer_email" value="email@foo.com">
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="07870 XXXXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="billing_first_name" value="Horatio">
<input type="hidden" name="billing_last_name" value="Doodlebug">
<input type="hidden" name="billing_address1" value="Blah">
<input type="hidden" name="billing_city" value="Blah">
<input type="hidden" name="billing_country" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="billing_state" value="Foo">
<input type="hidden" name="billing_zip" value="XXX XXX">

<!-- transaction details -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="2,000.00">
```

Am I missing anything in my form that is causing the transaction for 3D Secure cards to fail, or are 3D secure cards themselves unable to be tested in the sandbox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct; Maestro cards require 3D Secure authentication, and you cannot currently test 3D Secure authentication in the PayPal Sandbox with the Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution product.